# Command line character encoding from PHP's exec()

Tags: php, encoding, exec, character-encoding

I'm trying to pass UTF-8 text as an argument to a command line program using php's `exec` function and have been having problems. I suspect it's due to character encoding issues.

When I call `locale charmap` from the command line, I get: `UTF-8`.

But when I do:

```
<?php echo exec('locale charmap'); ?>
```

I get

`ANSI_X3.4-1968`

How can I change this? It's not something I want to set once -- I'll be working with different languages / encodings potentially so each call to `exec()` could require a different one.  But even knowing how to set it to `UTF-8` once would be helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Prefix the command with `LANG = <language>.UTF8`.

Example:

```
$ php -r "echo exec('LANG=\"en_US.UTF8\" locale charmap');"
UTF-8
$ php -r "echo exec('LANG=\"en_US.iso88591\" locale charmap');
ISO-8859-1
```

You should have the locale installed.

Comment: Life saver. Much appreciated.