# PHP exec change encoding

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, exec

I need to address UTF-8 filenames with the php exec command. The problem is that the php `exec` command does not seem to understand utf-8. I use something like this:

```
echo exec('locale charmap');
```

returns `ANSI_X3.4-1968`

looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410424/command-line-character-encoding-from-phps-exec) SO question, the solution lookes like that:

```
echo exec('LANG=de_DE.utf8; locale charmap');
```

But I still get the same output: `ANSI_X3.4-1968`

On the other hand -  if I execute this php command on the bash command line:

```
php -r "echo exec('LANG=de_DE.UTF8 locale charmap');"
```

The output is UTF-8.
So the questions are:

1. Why is there an different result be executing the php command at bash and at apache_module/web page?
2. How to set UTF-8 for `exec` if it runs inside a website as apache module?

Comment: Wait, are you trying to change the locale of the process spawned by the `exec`, or are you trying to get the `exec` to change *PHP's* locale?

Comment: @Charles i'm not sure, what exactly you mean. But i found out the following solution (take a look below).

Comment: How did you found out what that your exec command returns `ANSI_X3.4-1968`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To answer my own question - i found the following solution:

setting the locale environment variable with PHP

```
$locale='de_DE.UTF-8';
setlocale(LC_ALL,$locale);
putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
echo exec('locale charmap');
```

This sets to / returns  `UTF-8`. So i'm able to pass special characters and umlauts to linux shell commands.

Comment: finding this makes me one happy man right now.  thanks for the q&a

Comment: This is great. I'd set the charset in a config file in /etc but after a server-upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04, that config was apparently gone. So it's better to set it in the PHP file to avoid future problems it seems.

Comment: Note that you can also specify `LC_ALL=...` right in front of your exec call (like in the original post with the wrong environment variables) so that it affects only that one call if needed, e.g. `exec('LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8 locale charmap')` - sometimes, this might look cleaner.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me a lot. I don't understand how it is possible for a language which is supposed to be "modern" and is pretty much the most widely used language in the world to default to a charset designed in 1968!

Comment: Did not worked for me, all my umlauts are still getting replaced by a <?>

Comment: putenv('LC_ALL=cs_CZ.utf-8') did the trick for me. suddenly my command with czech characters is not corrupted

Comment: @EdwardBlack unfortunately 'Did not worked' is not a valid error description.  Maybe you should describe your problem in an separate question.

Answer (score 5):

This solves it for me (source: [this comment here](https://x10hosting.com/community/threads/shell_exec-how-to-make-utf8.93993/#post-513728)):

```
<?php
putenv('LANG=en_US.UTF-8'); 
$command = escapeshellcmd('python3 myscript.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Solved exactly my problem. Thumbs up for the documentation!

Comment: I got `invalid input found on input connection` in R language `source()`called by php.  php-> shell ->R.You save me :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem. My program was returning me some German letters like: üäöß. Here is my code:

```
$programResult = shell_exec('my script');
```

Variable `$programResult` is containing German umlauts, but they were badly encoded. In order to encode it properly you can call `utf8_encode()` function.

```
$programResult = shell_exec('my script');
$programResult = utf8_encode($programResult);
```