# The php middot mystery

Tags: php, unicode

I have a Java app that I'm calling thru PHP exec. 
The Java shows the middot on the command line : "·"

But when the code is called from PHP in a utf-8 html page I Have a "?" instead of the "·".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="essai2.php">
            <input type="text" name="texte" />
            <input type="submit" value="Valider" />
        </form>
        <?php 
            echo "input text : ".$_POST['texte'];
            exec("/usr/bin/java -jar runner.jar ".$_POST['texte'], $variable);
            echo "<br>output text : ".$variable[0];
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any clue ? 
(I tried htmlentities, htmlspecialchars. And text file on command line is utf-8)

To give some more grasp to the issue :
on command line I do

```
java -jar runner.jar "le agriculteur est mort"
```

I get

> [le·la, agriculteur·trice, est, mort]

while on webserver I get

> [le?la, agriculteur??trice, est, mort]

the hex code of all this (following Rick James comment) is :

> 5b6c653f6c612c206167726963756c746575723f3f74726963652c206573‌​742c206d6f72745d

hope it helps

Comment: Where is the middle dot in that code??

Comment: should be in the variable "$variable[0]"

Comment: so I modified php.ini and apache conf according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605760/how-to-best-configure-php-to-handle-a-utf-8-website but no results. :/

Comment: `echo bin2hex($variable[0]);`

Comment: var_dump($variable) => array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(38) "[le?la, agriculteur??trice, est, mort]"
} echo bin2hex($variable[0]); => 5b6c653f6c612c206167726963756c746575723f3f74726963652c206573742c206d6f72745d

Comment: the 3F should be B7, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

ok for some reason php exec change the locales.
so the answer according to [PHP exec change encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961870/php-exec-change-encoding)

was to set locales before doing the exec :

```
$locale='fr_FR.UTF-8';
setlocale(LC_ALL,$locale);
putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
```

and VOILÀ !!

Answer (score 0):

If you start with hex `B7`, but end up with `?` (`3F`), that is probably because the text was encode in `latin1` (or any of cp1250, cp1251, cp1256, cp1257, dec8, geostd8, greek, hebrew, latin5, latin7), the n treated as if it were UTF-8.  `B7` is not a valid first-byte for any utf8 character.